# Tag does not exist in XML Namespace with custom uri-namespace

Tags: c#, wpf, xml-namespaces

I've just edited a custom control of mine with the following tutorial to provide a uri namespace:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/knom/archive/2007/11/02/wpf-tired-of-xmlns-clr-namespace.aspx

```
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.mycompany.de/wpf/CustomControls", "MyCompany.MyApp.CustomControls")]
namespace MyCompany.MyApp.CustomControls
{
 // CODE HERE
}
```

and used it like this:

`<my:ProgressIndicator Grid.Row="2" Height="6" ProgressColor="#23A4D3" />`

Now it says

`The tag 'ProgressIndicator' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.mycompany.de/wpf/CustomControls'. Line 111 Position 18.`

Why is this so? What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have a `ProgressIndicator` control defined in the `MyCompany.MyApp.CustomControl` namespace?

Comment: Well, I guess so... There's a class definition "public partial class ProgressIndicator" with the "business logic" of this control in it.

Comment: try this <Window x:Class="MyCompany.MyApp.CustomControls" ..... and then inside it use <my:ProgressIndicator......

Comment: Hmm... why do I need to move my Window to the same namespace as my custom controls?

Comment: I have never tried this before, but it's a nice feature. Perhaps the class needs to be decorated with a tagattribute of some sort, but I don't know for sure.